# Is it appropriate?

Tags: terminology

I'd like to know 
Is calling sb bookworm appreciative or deragatory?and why? Again  how about  saying  you are  grammar worm.

Comment: Hi Saeedeh, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: FWIW, *bookworm* is not intrinsically negative but it depends on how you use it. "No one would ever want to marry a bookworm like you" is negative; "how delightful to find a bookworm in this device-ridden class" is a compliment. *Grammar worm* is not a standard construction and is probably riskier, as *worm* has negative connotations; at best it would be used in a teasing way to a friend.

Comment: There are actual insects that eat books, and book lovers are named bookworms in reference to the insects.  "-worm" is not a productive suffix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookworm_(insect)

Answer (score 2):

With synonyms of dink [slang], dork [slang], geek, grind, nerd, swot, weenie, wonk [M. Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bookworm) and a sense of worms that actually eat books, one could very well think of **bookworm** as derogatory.  Even the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21460?redirectedFrom=bookworm#eid) says:

> A person who enjoys or is devoted to reading. Frequently somewhat
>   depreciative.

So it all depends on the context and the intent of the writer.  My sense is it is neutral! I have no knowledge of grammar worm.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciative or neutral. I think it would be unusual to use it as an insult, though not impossible.

"Grammar worm" is not an established phrase, as far as I know, and does not have a conventional meaning. If somebody used it, you could only tell from context what they meant by it, and whether it was derogatory or not.

Comment: Many thanks,I'd really appreciate all your answers , you all were helpful. You said appropriacy(appreciative - deragatory ) relys on context , ok,Here is an example i used bookworm / grammarworm. Plz take a look at  this example and say is it rude?           
  "Because You are said to be a bookworm/grammarworm ,i've bothered you to help me"

Comment: @Saeedeh: it's not rude, particularly, but it's somewhat incoherent. A bookworm is somebody who "devours" books: it doesn't mean they are particuarly knowledgeable or helpful (though it depends on what help you are looking for). As I say, a grammarworm is not a word I have ever heard, and all I can do is guess what you might mean by it. "I've bothered you to help me" is something I don't think a native English speaker would say.